# ui-router changes the path in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My routing is:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
  url: '/login'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/login.html'
}).state('chooser', {
  url: '/chooser'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/chooser.html'
}).state('admin', {
  url: '/admin'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin.html'
}).state('admin.users', {
  url: '/admin/users'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin.html'
    adminView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin-users.html'
})
```

In my view, I have:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a ui-sref="admin.users">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
```

When I click the link for `Users` it goes to `/admin/admin/users` instead of `/admin/users`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child state does inherit the parent url. So the mapping should look like this:

```
.state('admin.users', {
  //url: '/admin/users'
  url: '/users'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin.html'
    adminView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin-users.html'
})
```

And the resulting url will be `/admin/users`

The other option is to restart url evaluation, see: [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-):

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.

```
.state('admin.users', {
  //url: '/admin/users'
  url: '^/admin/users'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin.html'
    adminView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/admin-users.html'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

the state should be as follow as state inherits routes.
change it as follow:

```
.state('admin.users', {
    url: '/users'
    views:
     appView:
       templateUrl: '/templates/admin.html' 
     adminView:
       templateUrl: '/templates/admin-users.html'
})
```